# Oracle: Update with join not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Edit: The answer given by mathguy works perfectly. But I really wanted to understand why the first update statement isn't working and second one does. I know that `+` operator is not suggested, but in this case as the second table was in subquery, I had to use it.

Short Question. (Detailed explanation and Create/Insert statements below)

> What is the difference between these 2 update statement and why first one is not working as expected, whereas second one does.

```
update d_dim d
set FLAG=
(select case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t
where d.id=t.id(+) 
);
```

And

```
update d_dim d
set FLAG=
(select case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t,d_dim d1
where d1.id=t.id(+) 
and d1.id=d.id
);
```

**Detailed Explanation**

I am trying to replicate a workplace scenario. Unfortunately SQLFiddle for Oracle is not working so couldn't create fiddle demo.

I have 2 tables, `d_dim(ID,FLAG)` and `t_temp(ID)` like below

> select * from d_dim;

```
+----+------+
| ID | FLAG |
+----+------+
|  1 |      |
|  2 |      |
|  3 |      |
|  4 |      |
+----+------+
```

> select * from t_temp;

```
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Now I need to set the `FLAG` in `d_dim` as `Y` or `N`. 
If `ID` exists in `t_temp` the set it `Y`. Else set it `N`.

So expected output should be like.

```
+----+------+
| ID | FLAG |
+----+------+
|  1 | Y    |
|  2 | N    |
|  3 | Y    |
|  4 | N    |
+----+------+
```

This is the update statement I am using (Using (+) as in this case I need left join from `d_dim` to `t_temp`

```
update d_dim d
set FLAG=
(select case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t
where d.id=t.id(+) 
)

--4 rows updated.
```

But ID `2` and `4` are updated as NULL.

```
select * from d_dim;
+----+------+
| ID | FLAG |
+----+------+
|  1 | Y    |
|  2 |      |
|  3 | Y    |
|  4 |      |
+----+------+
```

If I use just the select clause after plugging in `d_dim` table, I get correct output.

```
select d.id,
case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t,d_dim d
where d.id=t.id(+)
order by id

+----+------+
| ID | FLAG |
+----+------+
|  1 | Y    |
|  2 | N    |
|  3 | Y    |
|  4 | N    |
+----+------+
```

I did some hit and trial and came up with this query, which seems to be working

```
update d_dim d
set FLAG=(select case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t,d_dim d1
where d1.id=t.id(+) 
and d1.id=d.id);

select * from d_dim;

+----+------+
| ID | FLAG |
+----+------+
|  1 | Y    |
|  2 | N    |
|  3 | Y    |
|  4 | N    |
+----+------+
```

So my question is that

> Why the initial update statement doesn't work properly and why is it
>   updating `null` for `id` `2` and `4`.

Please find the Create and Insert statements below

```
CREATE TABLE d_dim (id int, flag varchar2(4));

INSERT ALL INTO d_dim (id, flag) VALUES (1, NULL)
    INTO d_dim (id, flag) VALUES (2, NULL)
    INTO d_dim (id, flag) VALUES (3, NULL)
    INTO d_dim (id, flag) VALUES (4, NULL)
SELECT * FROM dual;

CREATE TABLE t_temp (id int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t_temp (id) VALUES (1)
    INTO t_temp (id) VALUES (3)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: stop using the `(+)` operator. Use a proper `left join` instead. Even Oracle recommends that.

Comment: I don't do generally but in this case, the table in the join was outside the subquery. So had to use. Any alternative method would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second query you have an outer join. In the first query you don't have any kind of join; you simply have a select from t, with a where clause where there is a (+) after t.id. I don't know why that syntax doesn't return an error; but when d.id doesn't exist in t, that subquery returns no rows, and that's how update works when the update value is supposed to be the output of a scalar subquery: if the subquery returns no rows, the update statement will update the field with NULL.

You didn't ask for a different way to make the update work, but if you want to see one, here it is. No doubt you know how to do this; offering it for the benefit of other forum members.

```
update d_dim 
    set FLAG = case when id in (select id from t_temp) then 'Y' else 'N' end;
```

**EDIT**:  It seems the OP didn't fully understand my point so here are more details.

The Oracle documentation states explicitly:

***•The (+) operator does not produce an outer join if you specify one table in the outer query and the other table in an inner query.***

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm

(under the heading "Outer Joins", after the "See Also" box)

Comment: This does the work perfectly. But I really wanted to know what is the difference in both update statements. I am gonna start a bounty on the question. But thanks for an easy alternative way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: As it was explained by @mathguy, the problem is that you are using the (+) on the where clause of your inner select in the first update. The (+) sign is used when you are joining tables, so it should not be used in the first update statement. What is strange is the fact that you did not receive a syntax error. And, by the way, the join syntax using (+) is deprecated, so avoid to use it. Use INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN instead.

Comment: All my comment above to say: You have your answer, it was given by @mathguy.

Comment: @utsav - sorry you had to waste reputation points on this (hopefully you don't care - that would be a definite plus). If my answer wasn't clear enough, you could have just said so and waited for answers.

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks. `The (+) operator does not produce an outer join if you specify one table in the outer query and the other table in an inner query.` This statement clears the difference between both queries and why is it getting `null` for the `id`s that don't match. +50 to you :)

Comment: It will let me allow you the bounty in 10 hrs. Will do it then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

An update statement would update based on whether the condition was satisfied for the update as specified in the subselect clause.

When you mention
update d_dim d
set FLAG=
(select case when t.id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as FLAG
from t_temp t
where d.id=t.id(+) 
);

This statement would be executed only when d.id is equal to t.id. In your case, for id=2, d.id is 2, t.id is null. 2 is NOT equal to null, so the update has no effect on id 2.